# What does it mean to preserves the subspaces in Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am trying to understand the reason behind [Gram‐Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). I understand the algorithm and have no problem finding orthogonal basis for a set of vectors. I also understand what advantage orthogonal basis gives me.

In the beginning I did not understand why I can not just take any orthogonal basis and claim that this is the basis for my set of vectors, but then I read that Gram Schmidt **also preserves the subspaces**.

The problem is that I can not understand what exactly does this mean and why would I care about it.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt procedure (more precisely the linear map that maps the original basis to the orthonormalised basis) **does not preserve** subspaces in general. In fact the only linear operators that do that are scalar multiples of the identity. What is preserved is a _very special_ sequence (called a flag) of subspaces, those that are spanned by an initial subset of the basis vectors.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thank you,  can you please write this as an answer (would be helpful if you will add more details, because it is kind of fuzzy for me). I am reading this [explanation](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/algebra/linear-algebra/real-euclidean-vector-spaces/projection-onto-a-subspace) and they clearly state that `It is important to understand that this process not only produces an orthogonal basis B′ for the space, but also preserves the subspaces.`

Comment: Yes that text is awfully sloppy in its formulation. What they mean is that _those spaces used in the algorithm_ to project upon are preserved. In the (2D) example they gave that is just a single subspace (unless you count the zero space and/or the whole space too, but preserving those is unavoidable).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen really thank you for taking your time and explaining the problems with the text. May be you have some suggestions regarding a nice linear algebra book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gram-Schmidt procedure (more precisely the linear map that maps the original basis to the orthonormalised basis) **does not preserve** subspaces in general. In fact the only linear operators that do that are scalar multiples of the identity. What is preserved is a very special sequence (called a flag) of subspaces, those that are spanned by an initial subset of the basis vectors.

This relates to the question of what the Gram-Schmidt procedure is useful for anyway. It is certainly *not needed* to establish the fact that the (Euclidean) vector space has an orthonormal basis, because for that a simple induction on the dimension will do. As long as the dimension is nonzero, choose some nonzero vector $v$, divide it by the nonzero scalar $\|v\|$ to obtain a unit vector, then restrict to its orthogonal complement $v^\perp$ which is a Euclidean vector space of lower dimension; the induction hypothesis provides an orthonormal basis for $v^\perp$, which together with the normalised $v$ forms an orthonormal basis for the whole space.

But this does not provide any specific basis (one is randomly choosing vectors all the time), and sometimes one wants a basis that has some fixed relation to an initially given but arbitrary basis$~\mathcal B$. Here "basis" as usual means ordered basis: its vectors come in a specific order (so that for instance coordinates with respect to the basis are well defined). There are many more bases than orthonormal basis, so it is inevitable that many different initial bases will lead to the same orthonormal basis after the procedure, but one may may specify a property that initial and final basis have in common so that the latter is completely determined by the former. Define the *standard flag* determined by an ordered basis to be the sequence $V_0=\{0\},V_1,\ldots,V_{n-1},V_n=V$ of subspaces where $V_k$ is the span of the first $k$ vectors of the basis (in particular $\dim(V_k)=k$). While many bases have the same standard flag, *orthonormal* bases are almost completely determined by their standard flag: two orthonormal bases with the same standard flag differ only by multiplying some of their vectors by$~{-}1$. Thus the set of orthonormal bases for a given standard flag is *finite*; it has only $2^n$ elements.

Now the property that links the original basis with the associated orthonormal basis is that *the two bases have the same standard flag, and for each $k$ their $k$-th basis vectors have a positive scalar product with each other*. The latter part is their just to fix the "signs" of the orthonormal basis vectors, which are left undetermined by the standard flag alone; it corresponds to the fact that one normalises vectors by multiplying them by a *positive* scalar. With this requirement there is exactly one orthonormal basis that matches a given initial basis, and it is the one found by applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure to it.

In the end whether the Gram-Schmidt procedure is really useful depends on whether the standard flag has any significance to the problem at hand. Often this will not be the case, but then Gram-Schmidt is just called upon as *some* algorithm that will produce an orthonormal basis, where in fact one one would do equally well.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that if you have a given basis $\{v_1, v_2, ... v_n\}$ and take the orthogonalization $\{w_1, w_2, ... w_n\}$, then $\mathrm{span}\{v_1, v_2, ... v_k\} = \mathrm{span}\{w_1, w_2, ... w_k\}$ for $k \leq n$. In other words, if you took the first few vectors from your original basis and then took the corresponding vectors you got from Gram-Schmidt, they'd have the same span.

One application that shows up a lot is that of orthogonal polynomials. If you look at the vector space spanned by, say, $\{1, x, x^2 ... x^n\}$ and defined an inner product between polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ as

$\langle p(x), q(x) \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x) \, dx$

then you could use Gram-Schmidt to get orthogonal polynomials (in this case, the Legendre polynomials) and the procedure will make sure that the new ones have the same degree as the corresponding old ones. These show up in some physics and numerical applications, among other things.

Comment: I am not sure whether I am right, but if I will take vectors  $(4, 2)$ and $(1, 2)$, then after Gram-Schmidt I will get $(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$ and  $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$. On the other hand I was able to take $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$. In my opinion both spans in $R^2$ so they have the same span and both are orthonormal.

Comment: Your statement is too general, Tom. What's true is that, for any $i$, the span of $\{\,v_1,\dots,v_i\,\}$ equals the span of $\{\,w_1,\dots,w_i\,\}$.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll make the necessary edit.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Tom's question is correct (I mark it as it is, but I am not sure), but I was not able to understand it from the beginning and it took me a lot of time to figure out the answer.

Preserve subspaces means that if my original vectors were: ${v_1,v_2,...v_n}$ and the algorithm produced ${w_1,w_2,...w_n}$, then

$$span({v_1}) = span({w_1})$$
$$span({v_1, v_2}) = span({w_1, w_2})$$
$$...$$
$$span({v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}) = span({w_1, w_2, ..., w_n})$$

Comment: That is not what "preserve subspaces" means; see my comment to the question. One might say "preserve the standard flag associated to the basis" though.